# How can I access information from a Node that is being passed into a method?

Tags: java, constructor, nodes

I have a Node(float coeff, int degree, Node next) that is being passed into a method. How can I access, for example, the coeff after its been passed in the method?

```
public Node(float coeff, int degree, Node next) {
        term = new Term(coeff, degree);
        this.next = next;
    }
public static Node add(Node poly1, Node poly2) {
        /** COMPLETE THIS METHOD **/
        // FOLLOWING LINE IS A PLACEHOLDER TO MAKE THIS METHOD COMPILE
        // CHANGE IT AS NEEDED FOR YOUR IMPLEMENTATION
        return null;
    }
```

If I, for example, wanted to create a new float variable called poly1Coeff with the coeff from poly1, how would I do it?

would 
float poly1Coeff = poly1(coeff); 
work?

Comment: "*would float poly1Coeff = poly1(coeff); work?*" - Why not try it out?

Answer (score 0):

`poly1(coef)` would be a call to a method called poly1, passing as its single argument the parameter coeff. Not at all what you want.

If `coeff` is a public variable of Term, then what you want is `double poly1Coeff = poly1.term.coeff;`
If coeff is a private or protected instance variable, then one must assume that there is a getter:

```
double poly1Coeff = poly1.term.getCoeff();
```